# Is temp object for assignment prvalue in C++ 17?

Tags: c++, c++17

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), in C++17 a prvalue is defined as:

> - computes the value of the operand of an operator or is a void
>   expression (such prvalue has no result object), or
> - initializes an object or a bit-field (such prvalue is said to have a result object).
>   With the exception of decltype, all class and array prvalues have a
>   result object even if it is discarded. The result object may be a
>   variable, an object created by new-expression, a temporary created by
>   temporary materialization, or a member thereof;

While it's clear that the righthand-side expression (`1`) of initialization like

`auto x = 1;`

is a valid prvalue since expression `1` initializes an object/bitfield, I am wondering shouldn't temp values on assignment, e.g.

`x = 1`

also be treated as prvalue? If so, why? The trivial expression `1`  does not result from a operator evaluation and neither does it initialize an object (since it's an assignment).

Comment: @Nicol I got you :-)

Comment: "*The trivial expression 1 does not result from a operator evaluation*" It didn't say "result from an operator evaluation" It said "computes the ***value of the operand*** of an operator". `x = 1` has two operands, both of which need values to be computed.

Comment: The wording is somewhat misleading. How the expression is used doesn't affect its value value category. Even if you write just `1;`, `1` would be an prvalue. Turns out, it does "initialize an object" (in the sense that temporary materialization happens here, since `1` is a [discarded-value expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization)).

Answer (score 1):

The actual definitions of these terms aren't super clear or especially precise, but the important part is that every expression has a value category and the value category for a particular expression is not dependent upon any broader context.

`1` is always a prvalue - regardless of how that `1` ends up being used. The taxonomy we have is that a *glvalue* is "an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function" ([[basic.lval]/1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#1.1)) and a *prvalue* is... *not* that. `1` does not determine the identity of anything, it's a prvalue.

Prvalues are typically used to initialize something (since otherwise they just get destroyed and don't do anything - `1 + 1;` isn't a particularly useful statement, while `x = 1 + 1;` is), which is why it's worded the way it is. But in here, both `1`s and `1 + 1` are all prvalues - even if this is assignment rather than initialization.